# gcc 4.1.2: error: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type

Tags: c++, gcc, hash, g++

I compiled a piece of code about hash function and got error: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type. I did Google it and it said to add the suffix "ULL", but I did have ULL as suffix. This suffix is supported only by gcc 4.4.1 and I only have gcc 4.1.2 on the machine and I'm not allowed to  install a new compiler. Is there any way to change the code so fix the problem?

Thanks,
-Tony

```
unsigned long long hash(string k){ //FNV hash
   unsigned long long x = 14695981039346656037ULL;
   for (unsigned int y=0;y<k.length();y++){
      x = x ^ (k[y]);
      x = x * 1099511628211;
   }
   return (x);
}
```

Comment: Split your constant into two 32bit integers, then do `x = thehigherbits; x <<= 32; x = x | thelowerbits;`, maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1099511628211` is also too big for a (32-bit) `long`; add the `ULL` suffix there, too.

AFAIK, GCC 4.*x* supports `long long` for all *x*.  Indeed, I'd have said that GCC 3.*x* supported `long long`, at least for the more recent values of *x*.

I'm having difficulty making your code trigger any warning, using G++ 4.6.1 on MacOS X 10.7.2 in either 32-bit or 64-bit mode.  However, I can get the complaint from the LLVM compiler from XCode 4.x (`g++ --version` output starts with `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)`) does complain until I add the second `ULL`, but only if I compile in 32-bit mode.  If that is used in 64-bit mode, it doesn't complain either.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to make that number ULL. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can write a constant expression that evaluates to the same number:

```
unsigned long long x = 1469598103UL*10000000000+9346656037UL;
```

This compiles with g++ 4.2.1

Comment: Be careful - the expression on the right only works because 10000000000 (10 zeroes) is too big to be an `unsigned long`, so it is treated as a `long long`, and therefore the whole expression is processed using 64-bit `long long` arithmetic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, I wasn't 100% certain about that, so I tried it before posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#define HIGHER_BITS 0xcbf29ce4
#define LOWER_BITS 0x84222325

unsigned long long x = (HIGHER_BITS << 32) | LOWER_BITS;
```

These two numbers were obtained using this sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        unsigned long long x = 14695981039346656037ULL;
        printf("0x%08llx, 0x%08llx\n", x >> 32, x & UINT_MAX);
}
```

Comment: Note that the computation is done in 32-bit arithmetic and therefore elicits warnings such as `warning: left shift count >= width of type` even in a 64-bit compilation.  The result is `0x84222325`, even in a 64-bit compilation.  Try: `#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { printf("0x%llX\n", x);}` plus the code fragment.  (Tested: GCC 4.6.1 on MacOS X 10.7.2.)